# Nsis Read Installed Path of adding more plugin dll to installed folder

Tags: nsis

I have stored install path in HKCU

```
WriteRegStr ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "Path" "$INSTDIR"
```

I want to read this path from the registry

```
ReadRegStr $0  ${REG_ROOT} "${UNINSTALL_PATH}"  "Path"
```

But it return empty string instead of c:\ProgramFile..
Is there any way to return this path

Comment: Are you sure that `REG_ROOT` contains the same root in both cases?

Comment: Maybe 32/64bit redirection? Please post more of syour script.

Comment: Are you reading it in the same process or is it a different process or a different application even?